# Animate widget alignment on scroll with Flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, flutter-web

I want to build an animation with two widgets that changes their alignment while user scrolls in a webpage.
This animation is similar to Apple webpage macbook lid up and down animation on scroll.
When user scrolls to bottom the two widgets becomes nearer and when user scrolls to top the two widgets gets further.